# Как отследить, включен ли экран Android-устройства?

Tags: android

Можно ли создать такой `Service`, который в фоновом режиме будет определять, включен у пользователя экран телефона, или нет (включен ли экран блокировки)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать сервис, который бы отслеживал включение/отключение экрана посредством получения широковещательного события **ACTION_SCREEN_OFF**

Пример можно посмотреть [**тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346958/listening-for-action-screen-off-on-android), например.

Comment: спасибо. так и планировал сделать. Мне нужно посчитать время, сколько телефон отключен. Я думаю перед тем как телефон уйдет в режим сна, взять текущую дату и время в миллисекундах, потом при включении взять дату и посчитать разницу.

Comment: Кроме того, о состоянии дисплея можно узнать в любой момент, используя метод **getState()** класса **Display**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getState()

Comment: по-моему только с 20апи будет работать getState

Comment: Да, верно, метод getState() был добавлен в 20 Api Level.
Что ж, если это неприемлемо(а это, скорее всего, именно так), то вариант отпадает.

Comment: у меня из активити все работает хорошо, но почему-то не могу сделать, чтоб после закрытия активити ресивер продолжал работать

Comment: теперь и без активити сервис заработал. просто перед тем как закрыть активити, я его вызвал